# How to transfer data from one table to another using triggers and transactions: postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, transactions

I am using Postgresql 9.5.4 and am looking for a way to transfer large amounts of data from one table (table1) to another (table2). This transfer needs to be from local (cRIO - controller) to remote server. But firstly I am just looking to find a simple code to transfer data locally. And then I will build on from there. Once the data is copied over to table2, the data from table1 should be cleared to save space on the controller.

So far I've been able to copy the data over from table1 to table2 and delete the row in table1 using triggers- the condition being a new row is inserted on table1. Here's an example of what I've done:

Created the copy function, which will copy name, family_name and age into the new database, db2

```
    CREATE FUNCTION save_table2 ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2
    VALUES (NEW.name,NEW.family_name,NEW.age)
    RETURN NULL;
    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Created the copy trigger - the above function will execute whenever a new row is inserted into table1:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER data_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2();
```

Created a clear function - to delete rows on table1 where the id number on table1 equals the id number of table2:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION clear_table1 ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=NEW.id;
    RETURN NULL
    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The above will execute when the row is inserted in table2:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER data_clear
    AFTER INSERT ON table2
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_table1 ();
```

This works well for small tables, but I fear it might not be able to handle large ones. The problem with this code is that if there is an error, fail or any mistakes the data may be lost forever.

Transactions seems to be a great way to avoid losing unnecessary data. Is there a way to use triggers and functions with transactions so that there is some protection against deleting the wrong information forever? Simply putting begin and commit around the above code won't do anything as the functions and triggers would already have been set by this point. I'm looking to find something that can manage the data correctly row by row.

Or does anyone have a better idea of how to transfer large amounts of data from one database to another automatically and delete the data on the first?

Comment: The code you have shown is invalid. Identifiers must not be enclosed in single quotes. And you can't do cross-database statements. You will need a foreign data wrapper for that. And finally: you don't insert into a "database" with SQL, you insert into a _table_.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for posting. I didn't use single quotes it was just for demonstrative purposes. I've briefly looked at how to connect to a remote database - but for now I'm just trying to get a basic model between tables on the same database. I'm very new to postgres so just trying to build a basic code from the bottom up. And my bad for misusing the terminology!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've made the corrections now - the above now shows the working code

Comment: You still say "*data from one database to another*" but the code only deals with two _tables_.

Comment: Anything a trigger does is done in the same transaction as the statement that cause the trigger to fire. If you rollback the initial DML statement, anything that the trigger did will be rolled back automatically (provided this is about a single *database* I am not talking about distributed transactions across multiple servers)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so what you're saying is the trigger function already has a rollback feature like in a transaction. So there isn't need to incorporate both? What about in terms of data transfer across servers?